# sql Query Taking Too long in production

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is working proper in local DB with small dataset, but in production it is taking too long, any help on this will be good:

```
SELECT su.orgid, arc.userid, 
    SUM(IF(arc.create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK,arc.processed_records,0)) Record_Week, 
    SUM(IF(arc.create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,arc.processed_records,0)) Record_Month, 
    SUM(IF(arc.create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH,arc.processed_records,0)) Record_3Month, 
    SUM(IF(arc.create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH,arc.processed_records,0)) Record_6Month, 
    SUM(IF(arc.create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR,arc.processed_records,0)) Record_Year 
FROM archive.log_archive arc 
INNER JOIN prod_db.user su ON su.name = arc.userid
```

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY su.orgid, arc.userid`. For performance, make sure the columns being joined have indexes.

Comment: already tried adding `group by`

Comment: You need that just to get the correct result. It doesn't matter how long it takes if it's wrong.

Comment: It's actually unfortunate that MySQL blew the group by standard out of its universe.  This is not going to perform well no matter what as the create_date > will blow indexes up.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to do the sums in a subquery before joining, so it can operate on the real table rather than the temporary table from joining.

```
SELECT su.orgid, su.userid, a.record_week, a.record_month, a.record_3month, a.record_6month, a.record_year
FROM prod_db.user AS su
JOIN (SELECT userid,
        SUM(IF(create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK,processed_records,0)) Record_Week, 
        SUM(IF(create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,processed_records,0)) Record_Month, 
        SUM(IF(create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH,processed_records,0)) Record_3Month, 
        SUM(IF(create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH,processed_records,0)) Record_6Month, 
        SUM(IF(create_dt>CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR,processed_records,0)) Record_Year 
    FROM archive.log_archive
    GROUP BY userid) AS arc 
ON su.name = arc.userid
```

Unfortunately, I don't think this type of summing can take advantage of an index on `create_dt`. The only useful indexes are on `userid` and `name`.

Answer (score -1):

this kind of query takes time. I will suggest below step
 1. optimize your query (check indexes on table)
 2. you should tune mysql server (change mysql configuration in my.ini file according to your database size and server configuration)

https://mysqltuner.codeplex.com/

http://mysqltuner.com/